# multiple fields in a combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a form which contains a ComboBox linked to an access database. I am asking the combobox to display the Incident ID, Supplier and Supply date of all records in the database table

The code is as follows

```
Private Sub frm_5_UpdateIncidentSelect_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Links dropdown menu to incident table in database
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim query As String = "select [incident ID],[stock supplier],[supply date] from incident"
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database.accdb")
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                connection.Open()
                adapter.Fill(dt)
                connection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim MyDataRow As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
    Dim x As Integer
    x = dt.Rows.Count
    For y = 0 To x
        If y < x Then
            MyDataRow = dt.Rows(y)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(CStr(MyDataRow("Incident ID")))
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(CStr(MyDataRow("stock supplier")))
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(CStr(MyDataRow("supply date")))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The issue I am having is that the data is being returned over 3 lines as follows

```
12
Supplier1
01/01/2015
13
Supplier2
07/01/2015
```

Ideally I need this information returned on one as follows

```
12   Supplier    1    01/01/2015

13   Supplier    2    07/01/2015
```

I cannot for the life of me figure this out, I am not great with VB I am afraid. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: instead of adding strings to the CBO add a class object with that info in it and override ToString to display it as you want.  This will also allow you to know what they picked without having to parse the text: `thisID = Ctype(Cbo.SelectedItem, Supplier).ID`

Comment: Also not an issue really but rather than For y = 0 to x  If y<x Then ... End If Next just use For y = 0 to x-1 ..... Next - you don't need to keep checking that y is less than x.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I would like to use the value in the combobox (well just the Incident ID) to then open the following form with that database records information displayed on screen. Would this still be possible after the data has been converted to string?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what Plutonix was talking about:

```
Public Class frm_5_UpdateIncidentSelect

    Private Class ComboBoxData

        Public IncidentID As String
        Public StockSupplier As String
        Public SupplyDate As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal data As DataRow)
            Me.IncidentID = data("Incident ID").ToString
            Me.StockSupplier = data("stock supplier").ToString
            Me.SupplyDate = data("supply date").ToString
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Me.IncidentID.PadRight(5, " ") & " Supplier " & Me.StockSupplier.PadRight(5, " ") & " " & Me.SupplyDate
        End Function

    End Class

    Private Sub frm_5_UpdateIncidentSelect_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Links dropdown menu to incident table in database
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim query As String = "select [incident ID],[stock supplier],[supply date] from incident"
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database.accdb")
            Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
                Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                    connection.Open()
                    adapter.Fill(dt)
                    connection.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        For Each Data As DataRow In dt.Rows
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(New ComboBoxData(Data))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Dim data As ComboBoxData = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, ComboBoxData)
            Debug.Print(data.IncidentID)
            Debug.Print(data.StockSupplier)
            Debug.Print(data.SupplyDate)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thankyou for the example, I'm learning what I can of VB but alot of this is still going over my head

Comment: Just keep in mind that vb.net does NOT have a mult-column combo box like Access does. The workaround is thus to have the hidden PK column retried as a value, and then the multiple columns have to be concentrated together as a single string which then in turn is used as a SINGLE column that "fakes" multiple column. This approach is kluge since when you select a given value, you cannot THEN grab the additional column values like you can in Access. The combo box in Access is 20+ years old and is still far better then anything available in .net

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal  "This approach is kluge since when you select a given value, you cannot THEN grab the additional column values like you can in Access."  My example shows how the additional column values ARE actually stored separately in the .Net Combobox via the Class instance.  The way it is displayed is controlled by the return value of the ToString() override.  You could store any number of values and display whatever you want in the ComboBox...

Comment: Fair enough – you still having to hand code the data structure and write code to fill the structure to accomplish this. Quite a bit of code to accomplish what takes one or in fact zero lines of code in Access, so it still “klugy”. The vb combo box could and should be a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

It's been over 5 years, but I hope it can help someone.
The solution is actually way, way easier.
I had the same problem while coding a simple Programm for internal use.
Try this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
ComboBox1.Items.Add(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0) + " | " + 
dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1) + " | " + dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2))
Next
```